Scrollable TimeText in Jetpack Compose
I am making an app for the Wear OS using Jetpack Compose. I want the UI to look somewhat like this:

This is the code that I have now:
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    TimeText()
    ScalingLazyColumn(
        Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        item {
            Text(
                text = "Title",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.title1,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
            )
        }
        item {
            Text(
                text = "Caption",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.caption1,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
            )
        }
        item {
            Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                Text(text = "Text content")
                repeat(10) { Text("Line $it") }
            }
        }
    }
}

The problem that I have with this is that when I scroll the list, the text comes underneath the TimeText which doesn't really look that good.

So I want to make the TimeText scroll along with the other text elements. If I put the TimeText() as an item in the ScalingLazyColumn, then it does work, but now there's a huge empty gap below the TimeText which is apparently a CurvedLayout.

How do I get rid of this empty space? Is there a better way to make the TimeText scrollable?

wrap your layout inside column
or add some top padding in ScalingLazyColumn

Wrapping them in a column just makes it so that the ScalingLazyColumn is now completely under the CurvedLayout generated by the TimeText, so now it's not visible at all. Also, I cannot even scroll to the lazy column anymore.

The empty gap is generated due to a CurvedLayout which is created by TimeText, which has the dimensions equal to the size of the entire screen. Outside of a list, this wouldn't be a problem since our content would then just be superimposed on top of the CurvedLayout. But when we use TimeText in a list, the rest of the list items appear below TimeText, not on top of it.
I couldn't figure out any way to make the TimeText behave as a list item while at the same time layering the other list items on top. I also couldn't figure out any way to cut off the empty portion of TimeText (Modifier.clip only changes what is drawn, it doesn't change the dimensions of the composable.
So I tried a different approach, by giving a vertical offset to TimeText which would synchronize with the scroll of the ScalingLazyColumn. Unfortunately there is no direct way to get the absolute scroll value from a ScalingLazyListState, so I had to resort to a hacky method by using Modifier.onGloballyPositioned on the first item of the ScalingLazyColumn.
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    val scalingLazyListState = rememberScalingLazyListState()

    var initialTimeTextOffset by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
    var timeTextOffset by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }

    TimeText(Modifier.offset(y=timeTextOffset.dp))
    ScalingLazyColumn(
        Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        state = scalingLazyListState
    ) {
        item {
            Text(
                text = "Title",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.title1,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
                modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned {
                    if (scalingLazyListState.centerItemIndex == 1 && scalingLazyListState.centerItemScrollOffset == 0)
                        initialTimeTextOffset = it.positionInRoot().y
                    
                    // for some reason dividing the whole thing by 2 seems to make the animation more 'natural'
                    timeTextOffset = (it.positionInRoot().y - initialTimeTextOffset)/2
                }
            )
        }
        item {
            Text(
                text = "Caption",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.caption1,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
            )
        }
        item {
            Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                Text(text = "Text content")
                repeat(10) { Text("Line $it") }
            }
        }
    }
}

This approach works for me, so I will mark the question as answered for now. But I don't believe this is the 'correct' way of doing it, and this approach might also be bad performance-wise. So if anyone answers with a better approach, then I will mark that as the answer.

 val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
          Scaffold(
                timeText = { TimeText(Modifier.scrollAway(scrollState)) },
                positionIndicator = {
                    PositionIndicator(scrollState)
                },
            ) {
                LazyColumn(
                    state = scrollState,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                ) {content here...}

I finally found it; the only thing needed was to add scrollAway to the Modifier of timetext, just like in the example
link here https://developer.android.com/design/ui/wear/guides/components/time-text?hl=en

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
